# If $A=[a_{ij}]_{5\times 5}$ such that ($a_{ij}=0;i=j$) and ($a_{ij}=1 ; i≠j$). Then find the value of $\det(\frac{A-4A^{-1}}{3})$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $A=[a_{ij}]_{5\times5}$ such that ($a_{ij}=0;i=j$) and ($a_{ij}=1 ; i≠j$). Then find the value of $\det(\frac{A-4A^{-1}}{3})$.

This question is fairly easy to solve by actually finding $A^{-1}$ but it is rather tedious to find the inverse of a $5\times 5$ matrix by Gauss Jordan elimination.

I was wondering if there was an easier method to solve this particular problem, since the matrix A is somewhat of a special matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: $A=J-I$, where $J$ is all ones, and $J^2=5J$.  Try to find $c,d$ with$A(cI+dJ)=I$.  This works with any rank-1 matrix in place of $J$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, by an easy calculation,
$$A^2 = 3A + 4I$$

i.e.
$$A \left( A-3I\right) = 4I, \quad \quad \text{ so } \quad A^{-1} = \frac{1}{4}(A-3I)$$

So
$$\frac{A-4A^{-1}}{3} = I$$

and the determinant is $1$.